# VS2019 Compiled DLL is not generating crash dump (WER)

Tags: c++, service, crash-dumps, windows-error-reporting

I have developed a service running on Windows 10 using ISO C++. The service and a DLL it loads are compiled on VS2019. (The VS2019 solution is created through CMake and the configuration used for producting environment is RelDebInfo).

In order to debug any unhandled crash in production environment, I have also configured WER CrashDump registries for the service. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps

To check if the crash dump is being generated or not, I introduced nullptr access in C++ code.
Here are my observations.

1. If the nullptr access happens in Service executable, I can see crash dump in the folder configured through WER Registries.
2. If the nullptr access happens in DLL that is used/loaded by Service then there is no crash dump created.

Is there any VS2019 settings blocking crash dump creation?
Any other thing I should look for investigating the problem.

Thanks in Advance.